# Why this array producer code doesn't work as it shows?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have used some code as bellow to produce new array from tow arrays :

```js
var arr1 = [['wo','ss'],['er','me'], ['lo','to']];
var arr2 = [['mine','yours'],['from', 'theme']];
var arr3 = [];
var temp = [];

//this will be an array of arrays that every index is arr2 + one index from arr1
var end = []; 

arr1.forEach(function(item) {
  temp = arr2;
  temp.push(item);
  end.push(temp);
})
console.log(end)
```

But after the result is not my desired and is not logical

```
[
 ['mine','yours'], ['from','theme'], ['wo', 'ss'],
 ['mine', 'yours], ['from','theme'], ['er', 'me'],
 ['mine', 'yours], ['from','theme'], ['lo', 'to']
]
```

Comment: what is that you desire?

Comment: when you do `temp=arr2` you making them point to the same place in memory, it is a referance of the same object.
so when you change temp by doing `temp.push(arr2)` you are also changing arr2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code **[`Array#push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)** method will push values to `arr2` which update the array(since `temp` is reference to array `arr2`) on each iteration.

Use **[`Array#concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)** method which generates a new concatenated array although **[`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** can be used for generating the array.

```js
var arr1 = [
  ['wo', 'ss'],
  ['er', 'me'],
  ['lo', 'to']
];
var arr2 = [
  ['mine', 'yours'],
  ['from', 'theme']
];

var end = arr1.map(function(item) {
  return arr2.concat([item]);
})

console.log(JSON.stringify(end))
```

---

**UPDATE :** Currently it creates the reference to the parent array updating one will change other. if you want a new array with the element then do it with **[`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** and **[`Array#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)** methods .

```js
var arr1 = [
  ['wo', 'ss'],
  ['er', 'me'],
  ['lo', 'to']
];
var arr2 = [
  ['mine', 'yours'],
  ['from', 'theme']
];

var end = arr1.map(function(item) {
  return arr2.map(function(v) {
    return v.slice();
  }).concat([item.slice()]);
})

console.log(end)
```

Comment: I tried both (mine and Pranav C Balan) in jsfiddle and both works producing your expected output.

Answer (score 1):

You must clone the arr2 for each iteration defining temp as new array each time

```
var arr1 = [['wo','ss'],['er','me'], ['lo','to']];
var arr2 = [['mine','yours'],['from', 'theme']];
var arr3 = [];

var end = [] //this will be an array of arrays that every index is arr2 + one index from arr1
arr1.forEach(function(item) {
  var temp = arr2.slice();
  temp.push(item);
  end.push(temp);
})

console.log(end);
```

This code works as you expected

Comment: I tested in chrome console